# .net session variables are cleared after request

Tags: .net, validation, extjs, svg, session-variables

---

**EDITION & SOLUTION:** 
After spending hours on this problem, I realized that Extjs chart save method unloads the page when it downloads the file. Since I clear session variable when user closes the page, my session variables were cleared automatically. *I am sorry for inappropriate question*.

Now it is more awkward that this download method triggers my session clear function but on my localhost it cancels immediately while it does not cancel on the server.

---

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**:
I use Extjs charts with my MVC3 project. And I am trying to save the charts using their save methods. Chart sends the data to 'http://svg.sencha.io/ to render and give response according to my request mimetype.

In order to give custom names for charts, I wrote my own code to get svg image and convert it to the png. I directed the raw data to my server. It worked well. I could save images as png files and give custom names. However, this request **clears my session variables**. I thought that input validation may cause to lose session data and I tried `[ValidateInput(false)]` header and `Request.Unvalidated.Form["input"]`. Everytime result is the same. I think it is related to the input validation. What should I do to overcome session problem. I don't want to disable InputValidation for all methods. Below you can find my codes.

Server c#:

```
 public void imageConverter(int width, int height, string type)
    {
        try
        {
            string svg = Request.Unvalidated.Form["svg"];
            string dateStr = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyyMMdd");

            byte[] bytes = new byte[svg.Length * sizeof(char)];
            System.Buffer.BlockCopy(svg.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

            MagickReadSettings settings = new MagickReadSettings();
            settings.Width = width;
            settings.Height = height;
            settings.Format = ImageMagick.MagickFormat.Svg;
            using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage(bytes,settings))
            {
                image.Format = MagickFormat.Png;
                byte[] data = image.ToByteArray();

                Response.ContentType = type;
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + dateStr + "\"");
                Response.BinaryWrite(data);
                Response.End();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

ExtJS Code:

```
myButton.on('click', function (button, e, eOpts) {
        Ext.MessageBox.confirm('Sure?', 'Save as?', function (choice) {
            if (choice == 'yes') {
                Ext.draw.engine.ImageExporter.defaultUrl ='/Statistics/imageConverter';
                myChart.save({
                    type: 'image/png'
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not a MVC guru but I have one thing in mind that may help you (if you are using cookie based sessions). But at first there are still some open questions:

Did the session change within the MVC Session store or did just the cookie change/get lost? Have you compared the cookies of the request and the response?

If it only apply to the cookies simply add the cookies yourself to the response cookie collection. You may either create new ones or just copy them from the request to the response.

```
// supposed to run in a MVC controller
foreach (System.Web.HttpCookie c in this.Request.Cookies)
{
    this.Response.Cookies.Add(c);
}
```

Comment: @tkcn So this was the solution?

Comment: no, I realized that problem is completely different and I find a way to handle it. Thank you for your contribution.